# Find closest string match from list

Tags: python, string-matching, difflib

I would like to troubleshoot an incorrect user input.
It's exactly about finding the closest match from the "database".

```
database = ["dog", "cat", "bird"]
user_input = ["dog", "ccat", "ddogg", "horse", "fish"]
for i in user_input:
   match = difflib.get_close_matches('i', words)
match
```

But I get an empty list.
Is there any simple solution to this problem? I haven't found anywhere how to get the result to the list using difflib.

Comment: review: not being a python expert here. code seems quite incomplete. what is "words"? where does database come in? arent youcomparing "i" instead of user_input[i] ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simpler way to achieve this is using *list comprehension*:

```
import difflib
database = ["dog", "cat", "bird"]
user_input = ["dog", "ccat", "ddogg", "horse", "fish"]

new_list = [difflib.get_close_matches(word, database) for word in user_input]
```

where `new_list` holds the closest match of word from `user_input` based on values from `database` as:

```
[['dog'], ['cat'], ['dog'], [], []]
```

---

Issue with your code is that you are passing `i` as string `'i'` to `get_close_matches` function. Pass it as variable, and then append the `match` word to the list. For example, here's the working version of the code:

```
new_list = []
for i in user_input:
    match = difflib.get_close_matches(i, database)
                                  #   ^ don't pass this as string
    new_list.append(match)

# new_list: [['dog'], ['cat'], ['dog'], [], []]
```